How to load picklist values from Apex in Screen Flow
I'm attempting to load picklist values from an Apex class into a Salesforce Flow. I've created an Invocable Apex class that retrieves the picklist values, but I'm encountering an issue. The values are being returned as a single string array (e.g., [Prospecting,Qualification,...]) instead of individual picklist options.
Please note: for the demo purpose I just choose the Opportunity Stage but I know I can do without writing apex invocable.
Specific Issues:
The picklist values are returned as a single concatenated string array instead of individual options.
The Flow screen does not display the values as separate picklist items.
Attempts and Current Approach:
I have created an Invocable Apex class to fetch the picklist values.
The values are correctly retrieved but not formatted properly for the picklist.
Request for Help:
How can I properly format the values so that each item appears as a separate picklist option in the Flow?
Is there a specific method or technique to convert the string array into individual picklist options?
Additional Information:
Here is a screenshot of my Flow screen for reference.





EDIT:




tl;dr: You're using the wrong type of Choice. Use the Collection Choice Set type instead.

By using a single Choice, you're coercing your data into a text value. Instead, take the following steps.
First, create a top-level Apex Class that represents a value and label.
public class PicklistEntryValue {
    @AuraEnabled public String value;
    @AuraEnabled public String label;
    public PicklistEntryValue(String value, String label) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
    }
}

Next, use that variable in your Invocable Method:
public class GetPicklistValuesAction {
    public class Output {
        @InvocableVariable public PicklistEntryValue[] entries = new PicklistEntryValue[0];
    }
    public class Input {
        @InvocableVariable public String objectName;
        @InvocableVariable public String fieldName;
    }
    @InvocableMethod public static List<Output> doAction(Input[] inputs) {
        List<Output> results = new List<Output>();
        Map<String, DescribeSObjectResult> objectDescribes = new Map<String, DescribeSObjectResult>();
        Map<String, Map<String, DescribeFieldResult>> fieldDescribes = new Map<String, Map<String, DescribeFieldResult>>();
        for(Input theInput: inputs) {
            objectDescribes.put(theInput.objectName, null);
        }
        for(DescribeSObjectResult describeResult: Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>(objectDescribes.keySet()))) {
            objectDescribes.put(describeResult.getName(), describeResult);
            fieldDescribes.put(describeResult.getName(), new Map<String, DescribeFieldResult>());
        }
        for(Input theInput: inputs) {
            DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = objectDescribes.get(theInput.objectName);
            Map<String, DescribeFieldResult> fieldDescribeMap = fieldDescribes.get(theInput.objectName);
            DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = fieldDescribeMap.get(theInput.fieldName);
            if(fieldDescribe == null) {
                fieldDescribeMap.put(theInput.fieldName, fieldDescribe = describeResult.fields.getMap().get(theInput.fieldName).getDescribe());
            }
            Output result = new Output();
            for(PicklistEntry entry: fieldDescribe.getPicklistValues()) {
                result.entries.add(new PicklistEntryValue(entry.getValue(), entry.getLabel()));
            }
            results.add(result);
        }
        return results;
    }
}

Note: This code isn't production ready, and is only illustrative.
Now, create an Apex Action that calls GetPicklistValuesAction. After that, create a Collection Choice Set that uses the Outputs from Get_Picklist_Values. Finally, you can assign that value to the Picklist field you created. Your picklist should now show the correct values as options.

Edit: Given the code above, the setup of the flow looks like this:












thanks @sfdcfox and I think I'm suck in creating the variable in the screen flow i have assign the input but when it comes to the output variable I have created TEXT with Allow multiple values (collection) but that variable is no showing when I try to select ?

Please see my edit section and I have added the screen shot, my main problem is not figuring out how to assign the variable to the output that I'm getting from the apex and I did safe and try to refresh the page.

@Nick I knew I should have added screenshots. Give me a bit, I'll edit.

@Nick Edited. This should give you enough to implement.

Thank you so much for the screenshots, I will go through and try to understand.

This was very helpful but I had to do one more step to get this to work. Before creating the Collection Choice Set. I had to create an apex defined variable (allow multiple values/collection) which could hold the output from the apex action.


Then I made the Collection Choice Set from that.


